# Пишу на subline text как внутрб установить какойто pip

Tags: python, pip, sublime-text-3, colorama

Я только начал изучать python и хочу написать своего первого бота в тг или хотя-бы покрасить мой простенький калькулятор, но столкнулся с проблемой. Не могу понять как установить [Оки скачать] pip внутырь subline text,
мне кажется я перепробовал уже все что можно)) И в cmd устанавливал, и в package control install package искал)) Помогите пожалуйста решить эту простейшую задачу... В силу моей не опытности в этом вопросе я бессилен

Answer (score 0):

Нужно установить пакетный менеджер,попробуйте так,если не получалось до этого.
Нажмите на клавиатуре Ctrl + Shift + P (для Windows и Linux), чтобы открыть панель команд.
Введите "Install Package Control" и нажмите Enter. Это установит пакетный менеджер Sublime Text, если он еще не установлен.
После установки Package Control откройте панель команд снова (Ctrl + Shift + P или) и введите "Package Control: Install Package" и нажмите Enter.
Введите "Python" и нажмите Enter, чтобы установить пакет Python.